# Using bash to export a comma separated list to html

Tags: bash, shell, html, css

I've got a cxomma-separated csv that I want to turn into custom html, and I ran into another script which did it, but it's been nothing but issues for me since I use https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php to run it.

Here's the script I found: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/convert-csv-to-html-table

My problem is that my output needs to be a bit different, and something about ECHO is really putting up a fight. So here's an example of my list:

> Product,100 usd
>   Now using this script I want to convert that to look like:
>   Product**100 usd**

Basically separating the list into 2 cells. But echo keeps stripping out "'s so it's just a mess. I don't know if it's because the bash emulator wraps lines, but I keep getting errors, where it seems to assume >< and tr as well as td is a command.

Currently my script looks like this, and it reflects how much i've stuggled with echo..:

```
while read INPUT ; do
echo ""<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';"";
echo ""onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';>";
echo ""<td>${INPUT//,/</td><td><b>}</b></td></tr>";""
done
```

And that generates:

```
$bash -f main.sh
main.sh: line 2: tr: No such file or directory
main.sh: line 4: ;
echo <td>six</td><td><b>nine</td><td><b>twelve</b></td></tr>: No such file or directory
main.sh: line 4: : command not found
```

I've experimented like crazy with echo, but now I'm at my wit's end. Any and all help greatly and gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 7):

Your quoting is wrong, specifically the double double-quotes.

Let's break down what you have, the bits concatenated together

```
echo ""<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';"";
```

1. the echo command
2. an empty string `""`
3. a redirection `<tr` -- this is where the "file not found" error comes from
4. a space
5. a string `onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';"`
6. an open quote and semicolon, the first character of the next string

To fix your echo commands:

```
while read INPUT ; do
echo "<tr onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66'\""
echo "onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5'>"
echo "<td>${INPUT//,/<\/td><td><b>}</b></td></tr>"
done
```

When you have a blend of single and double quotes, a heredoc is very readable. Also, use the `read` command to separate your CSV line.

```
while IFS=, read -r first second ; do
    cat <<END_HTML
        <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5'">
        <td>$first</td><td><b>$second</b></td>
        </tr>
END_HTML
done
```

Comment: `echo` doesn't read from stdin, so a heredoc would not be useful here.  Perhaps you meant to use `cat` in that last snippet instead?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably barking up the wrong tree with echo, probably sed or awk or perl or something else might be a better solution, but to just get your echo strings working you could escape the double-quotes and dollar signs you want printed, like:

```
#Added  \                 \                                      \
$ echo "\"<tr onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';\"";
"<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';"

$ echo "\"onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';>"
"onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';>

$ echo "\"<td>\${INPUT//,/</td><td><b>}</b></td></tr>\";\""
"<td>${INPUT//,/</td><td><b>}</b></td></tr>";"
```

`man bash` has a lot more info, see the section on Quoting, and watch out for things like:

> metacharacter
> A character that, when unquoted, separates words.  One of the following:
>
> ```
> |  & ; ( ) < > space tab newline
> ```
>
> control operator
> A token that performs a control function.  It is one of the following symbols:
>
> ```
> || & && ; ;; ;& ;;& ( ) | |& <newline>
> ```

Comment: Ok, so let's forget echo .. what am I looking at in whatever's more convenient, like sed, awk or perl?

Answer (score 0):

SO I've not scripted in shell in ages, much less used it for years .. But i did try the latter solution you presented, and when i do: cat prices.csv | sh test2.sh it returns nothing but blanks.

When i try the first solution I get: 
~$ cat prices.csv |sh test2.sh
test2.sh: 4: test2.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

So not sure if im using solution #2 wrong, and dont know why solution #1 does that still?

Comment: The files im using is comma separated textfiles, not csv's, forgot this.